# Why is my request queueing time so high?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, mod-ssl

I am running a Rails application server. My setup is:

- Apache 2, using mod_ssl for both https and ssl client certificates
- Phusion Passenger 5
- Rails 4
- Ruby 2.1

I use NewRelic to monitor the running application. I recently enabled monitoring for request queueing delay, mainly out of curiosity. I was surprised to find that the delay in the request queue is often as long or longer than the actual ruby code and database execution time. ~200 ms seems high, right?

[image: Significant request queue delay]

Most online information indicates that this happens when the request queue is waiting for a worker to become available, but that isn't the case. As seen below, we're barely using our provisioned instances. During peaks, we rarely go above 30% utilization.

[image: Utilization of worker instances]

A few other notes:

- Apache and Passenger reside on the same server, so there is not a false timing issue due to system clocks being out of sync.
- Regarding SSL processing, Apache grabs the client SSL certificate and attaches it as a header in the request. The rails application then handles the rest of the processing.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

200ms doesn't seem that terrible.  The 'request queuing' metric is the measure of time between your web server logs the request and the moment the New Relic agent loads (after `before_filters`).  The way this is measured can make it seem like there is a problem, when one doesn't exist.  Your latency is nice and even, with no spikes that would indicate you are running out of workers or starving for resources/CPU.  You can use `watch passenger-status` to check this.  You can also double check the server's resource usage locally using Linux utilities:

`top, iotop, vmstat, sar (systat)`

Still want to hunt for optimizations?  Check out anything that executes before the New Relic agent.  Possible pain points:

- before_filters/before_action
- [Rack middleware](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/list-of-middleware)
- slow remote services DBaaS, APIs, AWS services
- [Web server configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html)

It will take some digging.  Good luck!